# Trying to Use If Then in DocuSign Formula

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to integrate an if-then-else statement into a DocuSign template under the Formula tag but having trouble.

This is what I would like to accomplish: IF ([DropDownMenu] = 1) THEN ([TotalA]) ELSE ([TotalA]/2).

I am getting an error that reads "Invalid Formula: Invalid Format. missing EndOfFile at 'THEN' at line 1:28"

I am not sure if this is possible as I have not found any solution on the web or under the help tools. I was directed to stackoverflow with the question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do if-then clauses in formula fields in DocuSign, however you can definitely do conditional fields which should allow you accomplish the same thing.  For instance, you can say something like "If this drop down menu has item X selected, do blah".  This doc shows you how to add use conditional fields at the product level to get you started, then search the API docs to lean how to use in your API calls.  [Conditional Fields](https://www.docusign.com/support/how-to-guides/Adding-Conditional-Fields-to-a-Document)

Answer (score 0):

One potential workaround for this is to use conditional formula tabs. Hopefully you only have a few options in the dropdown. Create Formula1 which is conditional if DropDownMenu=1, and formula=[TotalA]. Create Formula 2, which is conditional if DropDownMenu=2, and formula is set to [TotalA]/2. The two formula tabs should be created on top of each other in the template. If you have a third option in the dropdown, you need a third formula tab.